# .NET core 3.0 get Invalid runtimeconfig.json when starting console application

Tags: c#, .net-core

We are building a larger solution with .net core 3.0 and C#, where one of the projects is a console application that outputs an exe. I just recently started working on it, but cant get it to run. When I start it in debug mode in Visual Studio (2019, version 16.3.10, running on Windows 10), I get this message:

```
Invalid runtimeconfig.json [C:\loong-path\projectname\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\projectname.runtimeconfig.json] [C:\loong-path\projectname\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\projectname.runtimeconfig.dev.json]
C:\loong-path\projectname\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\projectname.exe (process 3312) exited with code -2147450733.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

When looking at the `runtimeconfig.json` it seems to be really simple, and correct:

```json
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "3.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

And the same goes for the `runtimeconfig.dev.json`:

```json
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "additionalProbingPaths": [
      "C:\\Users\\myusername\\.dotnet\\store\\|arch|\\|tfm|",
      "C:\\Users\\myusername\\.nuget\\packages",
      "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried cleaning before building, and deleting the bin folder before building, but the `runtimeconfig.json` gets regenerated and looks the same.

I've tries running it with dotnet from the console, but get basically the same output as from Visual Studio. Even when running it with verbosity set to diagnostic produces the same output (`dotnet run --no-build --verbosity diagnostic`), which isn't very helpfull. The same happens when I run the resulting `projectname.exe` directly.

I'm fairly certain that the program should work but that there is some other underlying error, because the same revision works on the machines of two other people. But I'm really struggeling to figure out what the problem actually is, because it really doesn't seem to be a problem with the autogenerated `runtimeconfig.json` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `dotnet` directly against the `dll` like this in the bin folder produced the actual error message: `C:\loong-path\projectname\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0> dotnet projectname.dll`.

(The underlying error turned out to be:

```
...
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Failed to find or load OtherProjectName X509 certificate from local computer/personal certificate store.
 ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
   at System.Collections.CollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection.get_Item(Int32 index)
...
```

Which was provoked by this:

```cs
var otherProjectNameClientCertificateColl = certificateStore
    .Certificates
    .Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, _otherProjectNameCertificateStoreThumbprint, true);
var otherProjectNameClientCertificate = otherProjectNameClientCertificateColl[0];
```

(It was the last line that failed.)

)